# nodejs request returning null body from server for a POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, httprequest, node-request

I am sending an http post request from node using request (https://github.com/mikeal/request), and I am getting back a null body. The same request getting sent from hurl.it is returning the correct response with the correct body. Another request getting sent from the same nodejs server to the same server is also returning the correct body. What is really infuriating is that this was working last week and is no longer working in nodejs.

My server.js is:

```
var request = require('request');

request({
        uri: 'insert url here; contains sensitive info',
        method: 'POST',
        body: 'insert body here; contains sensitive info',
        followRedirect: true,
        maxRedirects: 10
        }, function(error, response, body) {
                console.log('body in response is: ' + body);
        });
```

anyone have any idea how to fix this?

thank you.

Comment: Is `error` set? What does `response` contain?

Comment: Try logging both the ``error`` as well as ``response``.

Comment: body in response is: null
error in response is: null

Comment: as for the actual response, the relevant bit is at the end: 
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _hangupClose: false,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '<removed>',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        parser: null,
        res: [Circular] },
     ntick: true,
     response: [Circular],
     _destdata: true,
     _ended: true,
     _callbackCalled: true },
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON],
  body: 'null' }

Comment: I don't know if this makes any difference, but the body in the request is an xml string and the response is an xml.

Comment: Even if the body is an ``xml`` string it should have been printed as is but looks like server is not returning any ``body``.

Comment: the same request made from hurl.it is returning the correct xml. same url, same body. Other requests are also returning fine. this is the only one that is bugging, and only in nodejs.

Comment: In that `response` object, the body is the literal string `'null'`!

Comment: Hi Bergi, thanks for the comment. It helped debug what the problem was. The problem was that the server was throwing a null exception because it was expecting a user agent to be sent in the header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved this issue. The server I was posting to was apparently expecting a User Agent in the header that I wasn't sending, was throwing a null exception, and returning null. It has since been fixed.

Thank you.

Comment: and how did you add that ?